# How to fix HTTP 504 Gateway timeout exception

Tags: java, http, http-headers, http-status-code-504

I am attempting a GET request to another API to get a json response.

When I make the request with the code below, I am getting HTTP 504 Error (Gateway timeout error).

However, when I tried it through rest client tool, the request does not throw any error.

How do I increase the time gap in my code to avoid the timeout error?

This is how the call looks like:

```
HttpClient httpClient = getBasicAuthDefaultHttpClient();
String url= "http://XXXXX";
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpGet.addHeader("id", id);
httpGet.addHeader("secret", secret);
httpGet.addHeader("network_val", networkval);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

if (entity != null && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK.value()) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    restInfo = objectMapper.readValue(entity.getContent(), MyClass.class);
} else {
    logger.error("Call to API failed: response code = {}", response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}
```

*Please note:*

Could this be something to do with 'https'?

When I try with 'http' through my [Insomnia REST Client](https://insomnia.rest/) I get the ERROR: error: Failure when receiving data from the peer. 
https works fine without any error (https://XXXXX)

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In this code you aren't even executing your Get request.

Comment: I just updated.

Comment: The endpoint may not be listening on the standard `http` port and may only be serving over `https` so yes, try with `https`. Other than that, without knowing much about the server, there's little we can do to help.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I tried.

```
public HttpClient getBasicAuthDefaultHttpClient() {
    CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, 
    password);
    provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);

    //Fix to avoid HTTP 504 ERROR (GATEWAY TIME OUT ERROR)
    RequestConfig.Builder requestBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
    requestBuilder.setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000);
    requestBuilder.setConnectionRequestTimeout(30 * 1000);

    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    builder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestBuilder.build());
    builder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();

    return builder.build();
}
```